# Solidity support in Atom

Tags: solidity, atom

I/ve downloaded Atom.

Regardless of which solidity package I download, install and enable, it doesn't seem to work ie. I don't see any syntax checking, highlighting, correcting etc...

Do I need to pre-install something aside from the Atom editor? I'm only interested in local correct solidity syntax editing

tx/tony

Answer (score 3):

I use [**language-ethereum**](https://atom.io/packages/language-ethereum) for Solidity syntax highlighting.

Comment: tx. I tried that too but I still can't get it to show up in the editor when I install and enable it. It's as if Atom is ignorant of ethereum syntax control.

Comment: @TonyHontzeas try to turn off all modules and manually turn on to find out which modules conflict.

Answer (score 0):

I am quite happy with [etheratom](https://github.com/0mkara/etheratom)

Comment: etheratom looks great but I tried installing it from atom packages and cloning the repo and installing it using the atom package manager and it still wasn't working.